# iOS MDM Kiosk mode

Tags: ios, mdm, kiosk-mode

I have a supervised iPad with few applications installed.
When I push a kiosk mode profile for running only single app, iPad switches to single app mode.

What happens if there is an update available to the app running in the kiosk mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS doesn’t allow any updates in Kiosk mode. So, as an admin, if one needs to update the app, you would remove the app lock policy, then push the app update, and then re-apply the app lock policy.

[This](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/359506-update-app-with-kiosk-mode-enable/) post helped me